Generate wheel-package for specific python version using pyproject.toml
I'm currently transferring my project build pipeline from being setup.py-based to a pyproject.toml-based approach. Most of the parameters are easily transferable, however, I can't find an equivalent to
python_requires="~=3.11"

Of course, there is
[project]
requires-python = "~=3.11"

but while the setting in setup.py results in -cp311-cp311 in the package name, the same setting in pyproject.toml results in -py3-none in the package name.
As the package contains several dll-files which have to be compiled specific to each python version, I want to reflect that also in the package name (and ideally refuse installation if a wrong python installation is used). How can I solve that by using pyproject.toml?

Did you manage to do that?
